# Fastest way to clone a repository and get a log of patches

Tags: git

I have a very specific task that I am trying to speed up as fast as possible. Starting from an empty state I want to get the log of patches between two commits on a remote repo.

Here's what I have so far:

```
GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone --no-checkout --filter=blob:none https://${repo}.git tmp 
cd tmp
git log --no-merges --first-parent --patch ${base_sha}..${head_sha} > log.patch
```

The clone part is very fast! It takes maybe a second:

```
Cloning into 'tmp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4602, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1292/1292), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (367/367), done.
remote: Total 4602 (delta 1033), reused 1115 (delta 912), pack-reused 3310
Receiving objects: 100% (4602/4602), 447.14 KiB | 3.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3027/3027), done.
```

However the log part is slow because it seems to do one network request per commit in the log:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 4562, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1252/1252), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (341/341), done.
remote: Total 4562 (delta 1016), reused 1090 (delta 902), pack-reused 3310
Receiving objects: 100% (4562/4562), 440.43 KiB | 3.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3010/3010), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 4652, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1342/1342), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (389/389), done.
remote: Total 4652 (delta 1077), reused 1160 (delta 943), pack-reused 3310
Receiving objects: 100% (4652/4652), 449.91 KiB | 3.51 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3071/3071), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 2, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2/2), 9.82 KiB | 437.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), 12.78 KiB | 2.13 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1/1), 9.63 KiB | 9.63 MiB/s, done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 2), reused 3 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (5/5), 13.89 KiB | 748.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 2), reused 6 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), 25.50 KiB | 12.75 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 2), reused 4 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (5/5), 12.15 KiB | 12.15 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 1), reused 3 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (4/4), 88.69 KiB | 1.53 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1/1), 2.92 KiB | 2.92 MiB/s, done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 2 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), 3.12 KiB | 1.56 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 2, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 0), reused 2 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2/2), 2.41 KiB | 2.41 MiB/s, done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 10, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 3), reused 8 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (10/10), 28.52 KiB | 3.17 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (9/9), 29.26 KiB | 4.18 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 2), reused 6 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 2), reused 5 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), 139.48 KiB | 2.02 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
```

Each individual request is fast, but there's a lot of latency between them so this ends up taking about 1s+ per commit.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: What's the point of cloning if you're not going to do the logging using the _local_ copy you just made by cloning?

Comment: Rejecting all blobs with `--filter=blob:none` is the culprit for needing to make a new network request for each processed commit. Maybe replacing that with `-b <branch> --single-branch --shallow-exclude=${base_sha}` would be an improvement?

Comment: Seems like I don’t understand something fundamental here. I assumed there would be a way to get the diffs without ever getting any whole blobs (since I want to avoid downloading a bunch of large and potentially unchanged files). Sounds like I can’t?

Comment: Git needs to compare the trees to be able to diff 2 commits. Git does **not** save diffs between commits, it's **always** a full snapshot in every commit.

Comment: As you use partial clone, I guess your repository is hosted in Github. Github (or any other hosting service) has a feature to list commits and download a patch through http/https URL or rest APIs, so that users don't have to clone the repository.